# How to use stereotypes in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```ts
class Utils {
  constructor(map: Map, fn: string, parameters: any) {
    Utils[fn](parameters);
  }

  public static simplify(
    geojson: AllGeoJSON,
    options?: SimplifyOptions
  ): AllGeoJSON {
    return turf.simplify(geojson, options);
  }
}
```

Assuming I use it this way

new Utils(map, 'simplify', geojson, options)

Why did I give paramters the type 'any' and still throw this error?

May I ask how I should use stereotypes to address this issue?
This is a TypeScript program.

Comment: What do you mean by "stereotypes"? I don't recognise this as a typescript keywords. And what is the error message you are seeing? If you want to use the static function `simplify`, why don't you just call `Utils.simplfy(geojson,options)`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ① Please [edit] your code to be a [mre]; one way to do this is to copy and paste your code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nl8RBN), and resolve any problems except for the one you're asking about.  That means you should either declare all types and values you need, or replace them with native types and values.  Once that's done, copy and paste the code back here. ② "stereotypes" is not a conventional term in TypeScript; please consider replacing that term with something else, or removing it and describing it some other way.